# Create successive Batch script?

Tags: 7, batch-operations

How can you create a successive batch job in the Batch API?

For example, if I wanted to queue and assemble 1000 nodes as a batch, then process them in a second batch when the first batch is done, automatically? Do I just call the second batch job in the finished callback? Can it be passed arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried to do exactly this before but something tells me it would be tricky. This is from the [Batch docs](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/group/batch/7):

> The API is primarily designed to integrate nicely with the Form API workflow, but can also be used by non-Form API scripts (like update.php) or even simple page callbacks (which should probably be used sparingly).

I remember trying to set batches outside of a form context before and always resorted back to using a form as I could never get them to work.

You might have more joy than me though so you could try simply doing a `batch_set` in the finished callback like you suggest. Assuming you're adding some data to the `$context` variable in your first batch's callback function (such as the node ID) you should be able to pick that context data up again in the finished callback and pass it though to your second batch's setup function.

Hope that makes sense!